# indexOf - how to find a domain without a subdomain(javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
var str = 'somedomain.com';

var str2 = 'the string that contains test.somedomain.com';

str2.indexOf(str);
```

The problem is that it matches subdomain, but I need to match it only an exact domain, without matching the subdomain how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `RegExp` out of the domain to check and test if it doesn't have a point or letter/number/underscore in front of it. (Maybe it would be easier to just check for a space)

```js
var str = 'somedomain.com';
var str2 = 'the string that contains test.somedomain.com';
let rx = new RegExp("(^|[^\\.\\w])" + str.replace(/\./g, '\\.') + "(,|\\s|$)");
console.log(rx.test(str2))
```

Another option would be to split the string by space and check if the resulting array contains the string:

```js
var str = 'somedomain.com';
var str2 = 'the string that contains test.somedomain.com';
console.log(str2.split(/\s/).indexOf(str) > -1);
```

Comment: it is possible to ignore commas?

Comment: I added that in the first solution @LunenLumen. For the second one, you'd need to replace all commas in the string I think